# É possível enviar para o Heroku uma aplicação definida em docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, heroku

Bem, tenho uma aplicação rodando no ambiente docker, porém utilizo docker-composer.yml e não Dockerfile para definir serviços, etc. Só é possível enviar uma app se ela estiver montada em Dockerfile?  Sigo todos os passos da documentação do Heroku, que diz para enviar o serviço *web* (heroku container:push web), meu serviço está nomeado como *drupal*. Mas eu quero colocar em produção algo que está montado utilizando docker-compose.yml. É possível?

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
ccf70f9d1dac        drupal:latest            "docker-php-entrypoi…"   16 hours ago        Up 8 minutes              0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       Drupal8
0251597bb10d        mariadb:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 hours ago        Up 8 minutes              0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   MariaDbDrupal

$ heroku container:push Drupal8 --app ${aqui_nome_app_no_heroku}
 ▸    No images to push

Exemplo docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    container_name: Drupal8
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: MariaDbDrupal
    volumes:
     - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

No caso do exemplo simplificado acima, docker-compose.yml. Teria que refazer em Dockerfile para poder subir para Heroku?
Obrigado!

Comment: `heroku container:push web ...`: pela sua _compose_ não tem nenhum service/container chamado `web`. Está dando algum erro ao fazer _push_ para o _registry_?

Comment: @BrunoCésar Editei a pergunta. Olha lá! O push retorna:  ▸    No images to push

Comment: Estava "web", pq eu havia mudado para seguir a documentação do Heroku, então havia alterado(.yml) o nome do serviço front end de 'drupal' para 'web'